# How to populate a text box using ng-bind?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I am going through [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_first_application.htm) link and I am curious to do the experiment on a text box control using ng-bind. But it is not working.

```
<html>
    <title>AngularJS First Application</title>
    <body>
    <h1>Sample Application</h1>
    <div ng-app="">
       <p>Enter your Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>

        <input type ="text" ng-bind="name" />
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How can I populate a text box using ng-bind?

Comment: How could it not work? Here is the code pasted into a codepen http://codepen.io/NicholasMurray/pen/ogmLyy

Comment: hi...i asked how to do it using a text box...i never said the sample code didnot worked

Comment: Oops, see updated answer below, you can use {{name}} instead as ngBind replaces text content and not a value

Comment: sorry for not reading your question more closely :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As, *The ngBind attribute tells Angular to replace the **text content** of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and to update the **text content** when the value of that expression changes*, you will not be able to bind to an input box:

```
<input type ="text" ng-bind="name" />
```

You can instead use ng-value

```
<input type="text" ng-value="name" />
```

or you can populate your input box using the model within the value attribute.

```
<input type="text" value="{{name}}" />
```

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/NicholasMurray/pen/ogmLyy)